# drawing a circuit, nand gates

Tags: integrated-circuit, circuit-design

Task: Construct an AND circuit with 8 inputs, a circuit which implements the expression a∧b∧c∧d∧e∧f∧g∧h.

Condition: Use only NAND-Gates with two inputs to solve this task.

Could anyone explain to me how to solve this question?

Thanks.

Edit: My thought would be to do sth. like this:

https://crcit.net/c/df53a1d9

Could that be right?

[image]

Edit: My new idea:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3fjj1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please upload the image into your question so that the question will make sense if the link dies and so that we don't have to all follow links just to understand what you are asking. There's an image upload button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please name all ports. Please use the built in schematic editor by pressing edit and click on the schematics symbol.

Comment: Hint: two of your gates have their outputs tied together. What do you expect to happen if one is trying to output `1` and the other is trying to output `0`?

Comment: Did you test your idea?

Comment: You will need 2x as many gates

Comment: Yes, i tested it. But it doesn't work, that's why I need your help.

Comment: Each (& every) stage NAND must be converted to AND ,.... so your question was rhetorical. "Could that be right?"

Comment: @ThePhoton: It would be 0 if we had and AND circuit

Comment: That's what happens when you drive two terminals of an AND gate with different values. What you have is a wire driven with two different values.

Comment: Could you give me an approach on how to draw the beginning? Edit: it would be a 1 if we would use a NAND gate.

Comment: Your gates on the left edge are drawn correctly. Each input goes into a different terminal of the gate. Your last gate has both inputs tied together, and that wire tied to two different outputs. Just fix the connection to the last gate.

Comment: I've add my new idea into the question. Is it now right? I really do my best to solve this question correctly and to understand the given problem.

Comment: your notation is inconsistent and inefficient but schematic looks the same as what I showed. Any questions ?

Comment: So, the edited answer in my question above would be right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to be a bit lost. read *https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws#Engineering*

[image]
let me show one way.  Often we use X or Y or Z for outputs or f(ABCDEFGH)=...

\$Y=((A\cdot B)\cdot (C\cdot D))\cdot ((E\cdot F)\cdot (G\cdot H))\$

Since you must solve using 2in-NAND gates , I will use ! to indicate an inverted logic. (sometimes you will find ! used before or after brackets, but you must be consistent!)

AND = \$(A\cdot B)!! = (A\cdot B) \$ with both inputs of a NAND gate joined to make it an inverter (INV).

\$Y=(~~(A\cdot B)!!\cdot (C\cdot D)!!~~ )!!\cdot ((E\cdot F)!!\cdot (G\cdot H)!!)!!\$

Cleaner notation removes the dot for AND but leaves + for OR.

\$Y=~((AB~!!)(CD)!! ) ~ ((EF)!!(GH)!!)!!\$

I should have labelled the inputs with ABC etc but I was too lazy.

Here is what it looks like with [my simulator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%203%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2050%0A151%2064%20136%20112%20136%201%202%200%205%0A151%20112%20144%20152%20144%201%202%205%205%0A151%2064%20168%20112%20168%201%202%205%205%0A151%2064%20216%20112%20216%201%202%200%205%0A151%2064%20248%20112%20248%201%202%200%205%0A151%20112%20176%20152%20176%201%202%200%205%0A151%20112%20208%20152%20208%201%202%205%205%0A151%20112%20240%20152%20240%201%202%205%205%0Aw%20112%20136%20112%20152%200%0Aw%20112%20168%20112%20184%200%0Aw%20112%20200%20112%20216%200%0Aw%20112%20232%20112%20248%200%0A151%20152%20160%20200%20160%201%202%205%205%0A151%20152%20224%20200%20224%201%202%200%205%0Aw%20152%20144%20152%20152%200%0Aw%20152%20168%20152%20176%200%0Aw%20152%20208%20152%20216%200%0Aw%20152%20232%20152%20240%200%0A151%20200%20168%20248%20168%201%202%200%205%0Aw%20200%20160%20200%20176%200%0A151%20200%20216%20248%20216%201%202%205%205%0Aw%20200%20208%20200%20224%200%0A151%20248%20184%20296%20184%201%202%205%205%0Aw%20248%20168%20248%20176%200%0Aw%20248%20192%20248%20216%200%0Aw%20296%20184%20296%20200%200%0A151%20296%20192%20344%20192%201%202%200%205%0AL%2064%20128%2040%20128%200%201%20false%205%200%0AL%2064%20144%2040%20144%200%201%20false%205%200%0AL%2064%20160%2040%20160%200%201%20false%205%200%0AL%2064%20176%2040%20176%200%200%20false%205%200%0AL%2064%20208%2040%20208%200%201%20false%205%200%0AL%2064%20224%2040%20224%200%201%20false%205%200%0AL%2064%20240%2040%20240%200%201%20false%205%200%0AL%2064%20256%2040%20256%200%201%20false%205%200%0AM%20344%20192%20376%20192%200%202.5%0A) that denotes H,L for 1,0 where you can carefully click on any input ( without disconnecting it by dragging the mouse click ;)

So you see output is H only when all inputs are H.

[image]

Comment: I think I understand it by time. How do you get the AND gates, which the arrow shows to? I just understand that the OR gate comes from not (abcd) which is according to DeMorgan's Theorem not (ab) + not (cd). Edit: Do you want to show with the AND gates that they are only inverted?

Comment: Yes inverting both inputs and outputs results in switching inputs NAND  to OR  which is not what you want. So do you understand that you must use De Morgan's Law to test your understanding is wrong and that the solution requires inverting each NAND ( due to restriction in question)

Comment: I finally understood it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: so you now see the light of logic, now there are only a couple more rules, then methods to design it,  good logic but for language there are 144 rules of bad logic defined by Aristotle and Plato.  ha.  ( called fallacies )  Language and Black's Law (for legal) still use  these fundamental de Morgan's Laws for language

Answer (score 1):

You want to write your expression using boolean algebra, then convert it (if necessary) using DeMorgan's theorem to a form that you can implement using NAND gates. For example, say you have A + B (A or B). This becomes:

`A + B (starting equation)
(A'B')' (DeMorgan's format)`

You can easily implement (A'B')' using one NAND gate for the purpose of the inverted AND (as expected), and 2 more NAND gates as inverters for A and B.

Use this algorithm with any equation you have in order to get it in terms of NANDS, ANDs (NANDs plus one more NAND after it to invert it), or NOTs (use single NAND to invert)